# The image is not filling the entire uiimageview width and height

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uideviceorientation

I have the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.captureImageView.frame.size.width, self.captureImageView.frame.size.height));
[image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.captureImageView.frame.size.width, self.captureImageView.frame.size.height)];
UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();       
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.captureImageView.frame.size.width, self.captureImageView.frame.size.height);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);

[self.captureImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

CGImageRelease(imageRef);

//rotation
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
int degrees = [self rotationDegrees];
CGFloat radians =degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
self.captureImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

when capturing the image in landscape mode either left or right the image presented in the uiimageview is no filling the entire frame.size and is always "short"

can some one point what to fix/add in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Set the image view's *content mode* to *fill* ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode)):

```
self.captureImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Comment: @liva Did you set it when the view controller is first loaded?  It should only need setting once.

Comment: yep placed it in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using *autolayout* you want to make sure the image is pinned to the sides of the superview (either in IB or in code like I did below).

You also need to set the `contentMode` like @trojanfoe mentioned (in IB or code). I am using `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` (instead of `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`) to preserve the aspect ratio of the image.

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self addSubview:imageView];
NSArray *horzConstraints =
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(0)-[imageView]-(0)-|"
                                          options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                          metrics:nil
                                            views:@{@"imageView" : imageView}];
NSArray *vertConstraints =
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(0)-[imageView]-(0)-|"
                                          options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                          metrics:nil
                                            views:@{@"imageView" : imageView}];
[self addConstraints:horzConstraints];
[self addConstraints:vertConstraints];
```

Note: `self` is the superview of `imageView` in this code snippet.